# Remove cursors from atom mult-cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

Using Atom with the [multi-cursor](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) package (already bundled with the editor) in Linux, I can create multiple cursors with <kbd>Alt+Shift+Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Shift+Dn</kbd>. What is the shortcut to go back to a single cursor, or to remove cursors?

I can do it by clicking with the mouse in the editor, but I'd like to do it with the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Hitting `Esc` will leave only the cursor that was placed first.